# Knockout binding parents

Tags: knockout.js

Knockout bidning doesn'work. Can't access the "removeItem" function

**Html**

```
<div>   
<div data-bind="with: idea">
           <input type = "text"
            data-bind = 'value:itemToAdd' />
            <input type="button" data-bind="click:$parent.addItem" value="add" />
      <ul data-bind = "foreach:allItems">
          <li>
              <span data-bind = "text:$data"></span>
              <input type="button" data-bind="click: $parents[1].removeItem"                 value="remove"/>   
          </li>
      </ul> 
</div>
</div>
```

**Script**

```
var vm = {        
      idea: ko.observable({
          allItems: ko.observableArray(),
          itemToAdd : ko.observable("")
          }),
      addItem : function () {
        var item = this.itemToAdd();
        this.allItems.push(item);
        this.itemToAdd("");
    },
      removeItem : function (data) {
           this.allItems.remove(data);
    }
 };
ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

[jsFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mk_yo/M2xDF/4/) Would appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `bind` function to assign appropriate value to `this`.

```
<input type="button" data-bind="click: $parents[1].removeItem.bind($parent, $data)" value="remove"/>
```

First parameter of `bind` func is the object that will be bound to `this`, second parameter is the first argument of the target function.

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/M2xDF/6/